# submitting multistep modal more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop, smarty

I am creating a Prestashop module, which is basically a multistep modal for reservation, which is sent as an email after submission. The problem is that the last step of the modal needs to be an overview and I can't visualize the user input without submitting and refreshing the page (which closes the modal). I have called the prestashop attributes in the modal, so the user can choose and edit them there.

I am using this https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal (Progress bar with back buttons). I have 5 steps - the most important ones right now are the one where you choose the attributes - step 4 and the one where you see the overview and send the email - step 5.

If you check out the link, you will see that there are the buttons which navigate the modal steps in the footer. What I have there is this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-2" data-step="2" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 1)">Back
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-1" data-step="1" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 2)">Next
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-3" data-step="3" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 2)">Back
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-2" data-step="2" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 3)">Next
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-4" data-step="4" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 3)">Back
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-3" data-step="3" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 4)">Next
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-5" data-step="5" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 4)">Back
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary step step-4" data-step="4" onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-3', 5)">Next
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary step step-5" data-step="5" type="submit" name="button_pressed_reservation">Reserve
    </button>
</div>
```

Now when you look at the last "Next" button, you will notice, that it is type="submit". This reloads the page and closes the modal, but the user input is not displayed if the form is not submitted.

What i need to do is submit the modal 2 times without closing it, so I can display the variables that the user has input in the overview. For example in the fifth step of the modal I have the smarty variables displayed like so:

```
<div id="overview" class="modal-body step-5" data-step="5">
    <label>{$adults_reservation}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{$children_reservation}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{$customer_message_reservation}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{$customer_name_reservation}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{$customer_mail_reservation}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{$customer_phone_reservation}</label>
    <br>
</div>
```

and after the first submission I need to submit the form again, so that it is sent as an email.

NOTE:

I have called the prestashop attributes in the 4-th step like so:

```
<div class="modal-body step-4" data-step="4">
    <div id="step-4-attributes">
        {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group} {if !empty($group.attributes)}
        <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
            <span class="control-label">{$group.name}</span> {if $group.group_type == 'select'}
            <select class="form-control form-control-select" id="group_{$id_attribute_group}" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}" {if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected" {/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
            {elseif $group.group_type == 'color'}
            <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
                    <label>
                        <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}" {if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked" {/if}>
                        <span {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if} {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>

                        {/foreach}
            </ul>
            {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
            <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
                    <label>
                        <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}" {if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked" {/if}>
                        <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
            {/if}
        </div>
        {/if} {/foreach}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to submit your form between steps 4 and 5 ? Can't you just create a normal button to get to the "overview and confirm" page from where the user submits the form ?

Comment: Because if the input is not submitted, the values are not displayed in the overview.

Comment: They should be accessible in JS though. You could make your first submit button a normal button and - in pseudo code - do sth like: `onClick -> Gather Data -> Append Gathered Data to Display in Step 5 ` and your step 5 has the "real" submit button

Comment: I will try it and post the result, but it sounds reasonable enough.